# AWS Quicksight - How to deactivate sorting or sort data by month name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a CSV file as below

```
Mon,Month,target,actual
1,Jan,28.8,0
2,Feb,28.8,0
3,Mar,28.8,0
4,Apr,28.8,0
5,May,28.8,0
6,Jun,28.8,0
7,Jul,28.8,0
8,Aug,28.8,0
9,Sep,28.8,0
10,Oct,28.8,0
11,Nov,28.8,0
12,Dec,28.8,0
```

I have uploaded my .csv file on to AWS Quicksight and generated a simple chart.I have the month names in my x-axis and Quicksight is sorting it alphabetically and month names are not in the order I want. How to sort the month names in Quicksight?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to sort days of the week.  This is sort of a hack but I ended up creating a calculated field that would prefix the month name with a number so that it would sort correct. Keep in mind that if you data is not 0-padded, you need to do that as well (i.e. must be `01` instead of `1`).  So for you, this calculated field would be something like:

`{Mon}-{Month}`

If you make this your x-axis, the data would like something like

```
01-Jan
02-Feb
...
12-Dec
```

Still readable but sorting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a column called Mon with numerical values, you can sort Month using the column Mon

I went to

1. Click for more options on the Month axis (in the x axis)
2. Click on "sort by" and then "Sort options"

[image]

3. Sort By ~> Mon ~> Aggregation: Sum

[image]

Result:

[image]